# Is it possible to set the Session Timeout value to anything other than the pre-defined values?

Tags: session

This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10933/session-timeouts) but I will ask anyway.

I've a client that wants their Session Timeout Value set to 90 minutes. Is it possible to set the timeout to anything other than the values listed below (maybe by raising a case with SF)?

[image: Available Options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only legal values are the ones specified by salesforce.com. You could create a sidebar component to enforce a custom timeout, but that would only affect browser sessions and not API sessions.